# how to install and configure libboost and dlib for python 3.6 on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, python, boost, libboost

I have this setup

- CentOS 7 64bit
- Python 2.7 and 3.6
- pip and pip3.6
- dlib 19.3
- libboost 1.53

I've `dlib 19.3.0` `libboost 1.53` working properly with `python 2.7`

Now I need to run dlib and libboost with python 3. I tried several things but no luck. I get this error when i try to import `dlib` in `python 3`

```
import dlib
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/dlib/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .dlib import *
ImportError: libboost_python3.so.1.64.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Reason it says `libboost_python3.so.1.64.0` because i tried many things to make it work even trying to build dlib and libboost from source (which i've no idea what i was doing) but no luck.

I really appreciate any help you can provide to make dlib and libboost work with python 3.

Answer (score 2):

Dlib is not looking in the correct location for Boost. There is a workaround for this by using an environment variable (LD_LIBRARY_PATH) to tell Python how to find the libboost SO. Assuming your libboost SO has been dropped in /usr/local/lib,

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: Follow up with `sudo ldconfig`